# how to do breakline when varchar length exceeds 150 in MySql or php

Tags: php, mysql

i was wondering how to do a break line either on MYSQL or php when varchar length exceed 150? and the data is already over 150, the data contains around 400. So if i want to split it how do i do that? I'm new a guy from learning PHP and SQL. Can anyone give any example?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: or change the column to text instead of varchar

Comment: if using the function wordwrap can i put the length to 140? then until 140 it will split it out and continue to display the rest?

Comment: your question is not clear... You want to save more than 140 characters? you want to eliminate the characters over 140 ?

Comment: Do nothing with STORED value. Modify retrieved value output only.

Comment: @Vidal I'm not mean that, what i mean is when the length of string is exceed 150, then i just need to split it let say into half or split the string when reach 140 and display it and another 10 is displaying out in a new line

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the datatype in the database to hold 400.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column` VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: if let say the varchar i don want to admend it just leave it to 150 and i still to split it and display it out